# JPA/Hibernate - No query defined for that name

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, entitymanager, named-query

I have looked at all the similiar posts but i just cannot figure it out.
Any ideas ?
Here is my Main:

[image]

The Entity itself:

[image]

and finally my persistence.xml which is located inside META-INF in document root.

[image]

Annotation processing is turned on inside IntelliJ Idea(Ultimate 2020.2)..

Finally my build.gradle:

[image]

When i start the application however i get this error:

[image]

There is 1 entry in my database which i inserted manually. It should print out this element.
Any help is greatly appreciated :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the `NamedQuery` annotation inside a `NamedQueries` annotation like so

```
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(...)
})
```

This works for me.

Comment: It didnt work for me... but thank you still !!

Comment: @MajesticOl maybe the entity class isn't scanned at all. Try listing it manually in the `persistence.xml` just before the `exclude-unlisted-classes` tag. If that works, then it's a classloading problem and your best solution is to just keep listing the new ones you add in the xml.

Comment: This worked man ! Thanks a thousand times ! Is this a common problem ? Does this even have to do with my settings or is it more of an IDEA thing ? I want to avoid manually adding classes of thats somehow possible.... Still this works for now !Thanks a lot

Comment: It's not your IDE at fault. I use Netbeans and had the same thing happen when doing a Spring project for the first time last week. I could analyze the classpath scan to learn more, but it won't change the solution.